# What would the plot of partial derivative look like?

Tags: partial-derivative, graphing-functions

> Suppose, I have the following function:
>
> $$f(x,y) = -x^2 - y^2 + 4 \qquad (1)$$
>
> Partial derivative of $(1)$ w.t.r. $x$ would be:
>
> $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = -2x \qquad (2)$$
>
> Partial derivative of $(1)$ w.t.r. $y$ would be:
>
> $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = -2y \qquad (3)$$
>
> So, the partial derivative of $(1)$ w.r.t. both $x$ and $y$ would be:
>
> $$ \text{Gradient of } f = \nabla f = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial
>  f}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix} =
>  \begin{bmatrix}-2x \\ -2y\end{bmatrix} \qquad (4)$$

I have two questions here:

1. **Is the above description  correct?**
2. **What would the graph/plot of $(4)$ look like?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important [result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_set#Level_sets_versus_the_gradient) you should remember here is

> If the function $f$ is differentiable, the gradient of $f$ at a point is either zero, or perpendicular to the level set of $f$ at that point.

The level sets of $f$ are circles. For example $0 = -x^2 -y^2 +4 $ is a circle of radius $2$. And the gradient must be perpendicular to that circle, so it is a radius. Here's a sketch

[image]

Arrows represent the gradient, and colors the function. The circles are level sets

Comment: Could you kindly, show me a 3D plot as I am still struggling to grasp the idea? These arrows are not part of the actual graph. Are they?

Comment: Also, could you kindly tell me what tool you are using?

Comment: The arrows represent the direction of the gradient. e.g. at $x = 0, y = -1$ the gradient is $\nabla f = {0 \choose 2}$, that means that at $x = 0, y = -1$ there should be an arrow pointing *up*. I think representing this in 3D will only complicate things up, without providing any insight. Tool is [python](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/quiver_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-quiver-demo-py)